# NodeJS - PUG/Express: Display data collected from form

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, routes, pug

I think of this as a really simple problem, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a straight answer.

Simple use case:

1. Form that collects data, but does not save data to any database,
2. Run calculations on data (some basic math, done through the controller after 'Submit' is clicked).
3. Display newly calculated data on new page.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get step 3 working. I've created a route and view, and I'm rendering it on 'Submit'. I just don't know how to use the newly calculated variables from my controller on this new page.

Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated. The end of my controller function looks something like this:

```
var age_upper = age + 60;
...

res.render('ageResults');
```

Where 'ageResults' would be the page I want to display the calculated data on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the values to the template in the 'locals' using:

```
res.render('ageResults', {age_upper: age_upper})
```

Then use `#{age_upper}` in `ageResults.pug`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's what I'm looking for.